# ibtool to update .strings from .strings?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, localization, xib, ibtool

Is it possible to use ibtool to update a localized `.strings` file with an updated `.strings` file from the original language?

Concrete use case:

1. We have **one** base `.xib`, and **multiple** `.strings` files for each language
2. All strings files are translated for app version A
3. For app version B new strings are now added to the base `.xib`
4. We create a new (base) `.strings` file via ibtool

*Now* we'd like to

- **update** the already translated `.strings` files with just the new entries from the base strings file that have not yet been translated,
- but **keep** the translated text.

All [examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ibtool.1.html) I could find support incremental localization only if there are multiple .xib files for base and localizations.

Is it possible to use `ibtool` to basically **just add the new strings** to the already localized .strings files?